# Django runserver in windows just aborts with no error message

Tags: python, django, windows

I have been developing a Django project with some of the programmers using windows. Suddenly, all of them are unable to go on because runserver just aborts when accessing the port from the web browser. Just like that, with no error message or anything.

I guess it is windows issue because programmers with mac have no problem at all, and all windows pcs got the problem at the same time.

Has anybody known about any Windows issue lately and have any reference to try to find the solution? It, is a critical situation.

I got this information from Windows Event Monitor:

```
 System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Windows Error Reporting 

  - EventID 1001 

   [ Qualifiers]  0 

   Level 4 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2018-09-18T21:23:09.081612800Z 

   EventRecordID 1121 

   Channel Application 

   Computer DESKTOP-UMHL2MO 

   Security 


- EventData 

   2255961328469566825 
   1 
   APPCRASH 
   No disponible 
   0 
   python.exe 
   3.7.150.1013 
   5b330dc6 
   StackHash_89ce 
   10.0.17134.1 
   c8733c73 
   c0000374 
   PCH_CF_FROM_ntdll+0x00069ABC 


   \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER3360.tmp.dmp \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER340D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER341E.tmp.xml \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER341E.tmp.csv \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER343E.tmp.txt 
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_python.exe_54cf6c8aeb3ae10789acd854ed6a82b72d1c7c1_d4f4c736_01a13796 

   0 
   b7e6ab6d-2a75-4996-9e5e-c5d132578749 
   268435456 
   2bfa2eb7e405e3f06f4ec8e02a726569 
   0
```

Windows Event Monitor just informs of a crash of `python.exe`, but no other trace-back information. This is an image of the console for you to see that the server just breakes with no error raised or anything:

[image]

Comment: You should provide more info. How did you install django, are you using a virtualenv? How do you run the server? Etc.

Comment: Yes, I created a virtual environment with python 3.6, and Django 2.0 was installed using `pip`. I open a console window and run the server with `runserver` from the shell

Comment: With 'suddenly' you mean that was working before, but without changing anything it stopped working?

Comment: If it was previously working by running it with the method you mentioned, and there has not been any changes to the web application files, then you may need to look the environment the server is in. Potentially could be anything. By the way you describe it (if my flask knowledge is applicable) then it sounds as if there is an error which causes the web app to fail. The reason you "don't get an error" (which I'm pretty sure you do) is because the cmd window will close immediately if there is no reason for it to remain open.

Comment: Furthermore, in my somewhat short experience, I have never know a Python web app to be run in a production environment on Windows. People generally use Linux for this kind of thing. AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I meant with no changes, but now I know there has been a windows update. It is not in production, it is in development. The command window doesn't close, it remains opened, but ir returns to the command prompt without any message. The runserver just stops and returns to the command prompt. I have found some information in the Windows Event Monitor that says there was an application crash on python.exe. I am sharing it in the body of the question,